# How to make a "select all" option in html multiple select box using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I am making a html form which includes a multiple select box. 
What i want to do is to make a "select all" option in multiple select box so that if the user user click on that option all the options of select box will automatically gets selected if user deselect it all other option gets deselected. any ideas using jQuery?

```
<select MULTIPLE>
   <option>Select All</option>
   <option>value1</option>
   <option>value2</option>
   <option>value3</option>
   <option>value4</option>
   <option>value5</option>
   <option>value6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I store status (selected/unselected) of options in `data-selected` attribute on click event. Then use it to select/unselect all option of listbox.

```js
$("select").on("click", function(){      
  if ($(this).find(":selected").text() == "Select All"){
    if ($(this).attr("data-select") == "false")
      $(this).attr("data-select", "true").find("option").prop("selected", true);
    else
      $(this).attr("data-select", "false").find("option").prop("selected", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple data-select="false">>
  <option>Select All</option>
  <option>value1</option>
  <option>value2</option>
  <option>value3</option>
  <option>value4</option>
  <option>value5</option>
  <option>value6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it selects all values when i click on any other value.

Comment: @brhn.lok Oh, i think you want select all on click of any option. I edited it.

Comment: no @mohammad i want that if user want to select all the options so he/she do not have to ctlr+click all option the select all option will be used as trigger for selecting all other options

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using jQuery:

```js
$('#selectAll').click(function() {
  $('#persons option').prop('selected', true);
});

$('#unselectAll').click(function() {
  $('#persons option').prop('selected', false);
});
```

```css
input[type=button] {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="selectAll" name="selectAll" value="Select All"><br />
<input type="button" id="unselectAll" name="unselectAll" value="Unselect All"><br /><br />


<select name="persons" id="persons" MULTIPLE size="8">
   <option value="FR">Franck</option>
   <option value="GE">Georges</option>
   <option value="DA">David</option>
   <option value="LU">Luc</option>
   <option value="DO">Donald</option>
   <option value="FR">FRANCOIS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks @Gille Q. but i dont want any outsoide buttons i want an select all option tag in select box